# Erlang for Windows: Nodes Error?

Tags: windows, erlang, nodes

I'm using Erlang for the first time, and when I tried to create a node, it bugged out. According to the manual, this should work, but that may be linux.

Do i have to initialize something on Windows for nodes to work?

```
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10]

Eshell V7.1  (abort with ^G)
1> erl -sname ping
1> node().        
* 1: syntax error before: ping
1> node().
nonode@nohost
2>
```

Comment: I was starting the erlang shortcut from my start menu, rather than starting from Windows cmd. To resolve this, I added erlang's bin path to my system variables. Then ran the "werl -sname ping" from cmd. That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `erl -sname ping` command is what you run to start Erlang. Here, you entered it instead at the Erlang shell prompt, which is incorrect.

You should start over by first exiting this Erlang shell either by typing `q().` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl g</kbd> and then at the next prompt typing `q` followed by enter <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should get you back out to your Windows shell. Then, enter `erl -sname ping` and once you get the Erlang shell `1>` prompt again, you can run the `node().` function.

Answer (score 0):

The erl -sname  is command line for creating and naming a node. -sname stands for shortname and is used to name/identify nodes on same machine or same subnet on different machine.Once u start ERTS by erl -sname ping ,you are naming the node as ping and thereafter doing node() will give you ping@nohost instead of noname@nohost.You can find more details in Distributed Progrmming chapter of Joe Armstrong Erlang book http://www.amazon.in/Programming-Erlang-Joe-Armstrong/dp/9351104672/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1445756132&sr=8-2&keywords=erlang+book .The book is an excellent for beginers.